# Continuous Functions and Their Product

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Consider two functions $f,g:R\rightarrow R$. Suppose that $f$ is continuous at $0$ and $f(0)=0$; $g(x)$ is bounded but may not be continuous at $0$.
>
> Prove that $fg$ is continuous at $0$.

So far I have the definition of what it means for $f$ to be continuous at $0$. Where is the best place to go from here?

Comment: Hint: can you bound $|(fg)(x)-(fg)(0)|$ in terms of $|f(x)|$?

Comment: im not sure I understand?

Comment: what is the meaning of $fg(x)$?? Is it $(f.g)(x)$ or $f(g(x))$

Answer (score 3):

First figure out what is it exactly that you need to prove. Continuity of $f\cdot g$ at $0$ means that the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)\cdot g(x)$ exists and equals $f(0)\cdot g(0)$, which, since $f(0)=0$, is simply $0$. So, you need to show that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)\cdot g(x)=0$. Now you can use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition to establish that. You know that $g$ is bounded by some constant $M>0$ and that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$. So, given any $\epsilon>0$, consider using $\frac{\epsilon}{M}$ in the definition of limit for $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$. Done correctly, this should give you the desired proof.

Comment: why am I using $\frac{\epsilon}{M}$ for the definition for limit of f(x)=0 not f(x)g(x)=0?

Comment: because it works.

Comment: @user72195 The function $g$ magnifies $f$ by at most $M$ near $x=0$. To get $\epsilon$ for $fg$ you need $\frac{\epsilon}M$ for $f$ to take into account the factor $M$ coming from $g$.

Answer (score 0):

Here $g(x)$ is bounded. so there  is an $ \alpha  \in \mathbb{R}\ s.t. \ g(x)$<$\alpha \implies |g(x)-g(0)|<2\alpha $ ,

since $f$  is continuous at $x=0$, then $|f(x)-f(0)|<\frac{\epsilon}{\alpha} \forall |x|< \delta\ $

$|f(x)g(x)-f(0)g(0)|=|f(x)g(x)-f(0)g(x)+f(0)g(x)-f(0)g(0)| \\ \ \leq |g(x)||f(x)-f(0)|+|f(0)||g(x)-g(0)| \\ < \alpha.\frac{\epsilon}{\alpha}+0.2\alpha= \epsilon \ \forall\ |x|< \delta\ $